# Get-ADComputer -Filter name not taking variable for computer search

Tags: powershell

I've tried to create a powershell script which allows me to find the correct computer by it's service tag in AD.
So far I could do it by writing the service tag in the script, but when I wanted to pass it with variable, it doesn't let me do it, and shows this error:

> Get-ADComputer : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts
>   argument 'GCX0YY1"'. At line:2 char:1
>   + Get-ADComputer -Filter 'Name -like "*'$name'"'

```
$name = Read-Host 'Write the computers service tag'
Get-ADComputer -Filter 'Name -like "*'$name'"'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$name` variable doesn't get resolved if you use single quotes on your string. You could use a [string format](http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-f-operator.html) (alias `-f`) to get your variable in place:

```
$name = Read-Host 'Write the computers service tag'
Get-ADComputer -Filter ('Name -like "{0}"' -f $name)
```

Comment: You are welcome. You can also use double qutoes like `Chard` mentioned in his answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter "Name -like '*$name'"
```